# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element while generating RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, parsing

I am using the following script to generate a RSS feed for my site:

```
<?php

class RSS
{
    public function RSS()
    {
            $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        require_once ("../connect.php");
    }

    public function GetFeed()
    {
        return $this->getDetails() . $this->getItems();
    }

    private function dbConnect()
    {
        DEFINE ('LINK', mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD));
    }

    private function getDetails()
    {
        $detailsTable = "rss_feed_details";
        $this->dbConnect($detailsTable);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ". $detailsTable ." WHERE feed_category = ''";
        $result = mysql_db_query (DB_NAME, $query, LINK);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $details = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
                    <rss version="2.0">
                        <channel>
                            <title>'. $row['title'] .'</title>
                            <link>'. $row['link'] .'</link>
                            <description>'. $row['description'] .'</description>
                            <language>'. $row['language'] .'</language>
                            <image>
                                <title>'. $row['image_title'] .'</title>
                                <url>'. $row['image_url'] .'</url>
                                <link>'. $row['image_link'] .'</link>
                                <width>'. $row['image_width'] .'</width>
                                <height>'. $row['image_height'] .'</height>
                            </image>';
        }
        return $details;
    }

    private function getItems()
    {
        $itemsTable = "rss_posts";
        $this->dbConnect($itemsTable);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ". $itemsTable ." ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysql_db_query (DB_NAME, $query, LINK);
        $items = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $items .= '<item>
                         <title>'. $row["title"] .'</title>
                         <link>'. $row["link"] .'</link>
                         <description><![CDATA['.$row["readable_date"]."<br /><br />".$row["description"]."<br /><br />".']]></description>
                     </item>';
        }
        $items .= '</channel>
                 </rss>';
        return $items;
    }

}

?>
```

The baffling thing is, the script works perfectly fine on my localhost but gives the following error on my remote server:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://mysite.com/rss/main/
Line Number 2, Column 1:<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home/studentw/public_html/rss/global-reach/rssClass.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
^
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some extraneous character like a tab or a space that is getting echoed out with the xml file on your remote server. I'd use output buffering to clean that up before printing the xml.

**Update 1**

This is from the PHP website on [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
  // replace all the apples with oranges
  return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Instead of replacing apples and oranges, you could search for spaces and tabs.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "using output buffering before printing out the xml" - sorry I am very new to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the correct content type for the response:

You can try the following:

```
header("Content-Type:TYPE");
```

Where TYPE is one of the following:

```
text/xml
application/rss+xml
application/rdf+xml
application/atom+xml
```